# How to show content of rich text area in label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using an emoji picker input (One Singal Emoji Picker), which converts regular input fields to contenteditable rich text areas.

I'm looking to display a label which the text from the input in a label, but the approach I use with regular text inputs is not working and I'm not sure how to 'call element.val() on the underlying hidden input field to get the value of the contenteditable div'.

This is my current method which works with regular input but **doesn't work with this** rich text input:

Label that displays text:

```
<span>You have entered <span id="name"></span>  </span><br>
```

The input:

```
 <input id="idfield2" class="mirror" data-copy="#name"></div>
```

Script:

```
<script>$('.mirror').on('keyup', function() {
$('.'+$(this).attr('class')).val($(this).val());
});</script>
```

Comment: Your code is not correct, your trying to select the same input and set in it the same value you're already inserting, what are you trying to do ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using [MutationObserver (because too expensive)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) you may listen on the newly created **div.mirror content editable**:

```
$('div.mirror').on('input', function() {
    $('#name').html($(this).html());
});
```

In this way, whenever you digit something in the field it will be displayed in your span.
If you add an icon from the picker you need to digit some key in the content editable, otherwise you need to use the MutationObserver.

Moreover, I used .html() instead of .val() or .text() methods because the content editable can contain both text and icons. So, in order to see the icons you, after selecting one from the picker, you need to digit a char in the field.

Using MutationObserver you can write:

```js
//
// With Mutation Observer
//
var targetNode = document.querySelector('div.mirror');
var config = {  attributes:false, childList:false, subtree: true, characterData:true };
var callback = function(mutationsList) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
      document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = targetNode.innerHTML;
    }
};
var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// Later, you can stop observing
//  ...   observer.disconnect();
```

The fiddle is [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zphrev3t/3/)